# Moodle does not recognize math equations?

Tags: moodle, r-exams

I imported the `tstat` exercise given in Zeileis *et al.* (2014) to Moodle using `exams2moodle` from R/exams with default settings. But Moodle does not fully recognize the math equations written in both LaTeX and Rmd formats. Is there any way to fix this issue? The function `exams2pdf` works fine with equations but `exams2html` not.

[image: Moodle screenshot]

Comment: Could you provide your `Rmd` (or only the relevant part)? What is your `converter` (of `exams2moodle`)?

Comment: The Rmd is built into R/exams: `tstat.Rmd`. But the `converter` argument is indeed the relevant part and/or your `packageVersion("exams")`. Note that the default `converter` switched to `"pandoc-mathjax"` which requires that the MathJax plugin in your Moodle installation is enabled. If it is not, then switching to `"pandoc-mathml"` would be an alternative which works in Firefox and Safari but not in Chrome.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicion. I have edited your question slightly now, adding a few details, and I wrote up a complete answer that should be useful to other readers of the question. Would you please accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the vote counter on the left? Then the problem is marked as resolved here on StackOverflow. (The same would be good for your other question you posted regarding the students' comments, thanks.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since R/exams 2.3-3 the default in `exams2moodle()` is `converter = "pandoc-mathjax"` which means that the text (in either Markdown or LaTeX) is converted to HTML but the mathematic equations are preserved in LaTeX. The rendering of the math equations is then intended to be done by the MathJax plugin - a Javascript plugin that has to be embedded in Moodle and can then run in any modern browser. In your Moodle installation this seems to be switched off and you have to enable it, see: https://docs.moodle.org/35/en/MathJax_filter

As an alternative you can use `converter = "pandoc-mathml"`. Then the exercises are converted to HTML plus MathML for the mathematic equations. In that case no plugin/filter is needed but a browser that can render MathML. Firefox and Safari can do this - but Chrome/Chromium has no support for MathML.

For more details see the discussion at http://www.R-exams.org/tutorials/math/.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the suggestions. The following worked for me. As Achim has suggested, I left `converter` with default argument `pandoc-mathjax` and imported the same example to Moodle. Then opened Moodle's filter and set `Mathjax` to on and `Tex` to off. Everything is fine now.